# GmailApp.sendEmail not working with G Suite Account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, urlfetch

I am trying to use GmailApp.sendEmail to send a PDF of a google sheet by email. The script works when the sender has a @gmail.com account, but for some reason a GSuite account (not @gmail.com) sends an HTML doc that does not contain the PDF of the sheet.

Here is a snippet of my code, so far I only use GmailApp.. in this portion.

```
function printForward() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[3];
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
  var ssname = ss.getName();
  var length = ssname.length;
  var date = ssname.substring(0,length-15);
  const body = "All, <br><br>Attached is the invoice for the week of "+ date+"."+"<br><br> Thank you, <br> Elizabeth Moscoso";
  var fnumber = 2;
  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ss.getRange('Constants!T5').getValue(),"Invoices "+date, body, date, fnumber);
}

function printMidwest(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh = ss.getSheets()[5];
 var shName = sh.getName();
 var ssname = ss.getName();
 var length = ssname.length;
 var date = ssname.substring(0, length-15);
 const body = "All, <br><br>Attached is the invoice for the week of "+ date+"."+"<br><br> Thank you, <br> Elizabeth Moscoso";
 var mnumber = 1;
 sendSpreadsheetToPdf(5, shName, ss.getRange('Constants!T5').getValue(), "Invoices "+date, body, date, mnumber);
}


function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody, invcdate, foldNum) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  if(foldNum == 2){var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw = true' // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      }
  if(foldNum == 1)
  {var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId))
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw = true' // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      }


  var options = {
    headers: {method:"GET",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName+" Invoice "+ invcdate+ '.pdf');
 
  var mailOptions = {};
  var attachmentArray = [];
  
  if(blob){
  attachmentArray.push(blob);
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
  }
 
  if(htmlbody){
  mailOptions.htmlBody = htmlbody;
  }
  
  if(email){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"",mailOptions);
  }
 
  //save PDF
  const nameFile = "Forward " + invcdate + ".pdf";
  if(foldNum == 2){
  var forwardFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1-n7O87J0zN7ZnOtErhcJR_JDbkrjSyj8");
  forwardFolder.createFile(blob);}
  if(foldNum == 1){
  var midwestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17cQrFnAzy3B6jmwZB5-Osa6G7oC3YOLw")
  midwestFolder.createFile(blob);
  }

}
```

I am not sure why a GSuite account would not be able to send the email/pdf. Also, if I take out the sending email part completely and have the GSuite account only save the PDF, it gives the same HTML file.

Comment: Execution Transcript; do you see any errors? Can you place some `Logger.log()` lines to check if `email` has data?

Comment: Try using something other than a blank string for the `body` parameter of `GmailApp.sendEmail()`. Not sure why it would matter, just an idea.

Comment: make sure that you're actually entering this if statement: `if(email){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"",mailOptions);
  }`

Comment: I wouldn't be too certain, that the title is correct, when reading the last paragraph.

Comment: Hi ! What do you receive when the receiver is a G Suite account? Just an empty HTML ? Do you get any errors on the Apps Script code?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I have only tried sending the email as a G Suite account. When I do this the PDF sends as an HTML file; it is a very long text. The receiver is a regular @ gmail.com account. There are no errors when running the script.

Comment: Hello All, I figured out that the problem was with the url_base, G suite accounts return a different URL so fixing it using the solution at the link: [2] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165225796#comment3
 works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried by myself, an URL alike this should export PDF (assuming a proper oAuth2 scope). The PDF export would require scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`.

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + id + '/export?format=pdf'
```

This obviosuly would export the whole document, but one still can narrow that down later on.

---

You could also try using class [`MailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) instead of class `GMailApp`, which wouldn't trigger re-authorization requests that often, when changes were made to the script (this may be a factor). Unless one needs to access a user's GMail mailbox, there is no given reason to use `GMailApp`.

The oAuth2 authorization scopes also vary; class `GMailApp` uses a rather wide scope:

```
https://mail.google.com/
```

While class `MailApp` uses a quite specific scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
```

---

And from the question it is also not really clear, if you have the "OAuth2 for Apps Script" library imported; it's ID would be: `1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF`.

Comment: I will try using GmailApp

Comment: Huh? You already use that one. The issue may be not even getting the PDF to attach. And I've also wondered about parameter `exportFormat=pdf`, which appears to be redundant... when having the proper scopes, this generally should work (your script might be a little outdated, in general). I'd suggest to start over with the least parameters required to get any PDF exported and then add more parameters.

Comment: I found that the url_base was returning something different when using a G Suite account. Updating this makes the PDF print correctly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem; please consider accepting my answer... even if I couldn't tell the exact reason; providing an URL that is known to be working might have been the leading clue.